# Problems with connecting to IBeacon

Tags: ios, xamarin, ibeacon

I am using the example from [here](https://github.com/mikebluestein/FindTheMonkey) to connect IBeacon. I believe that my UUID is correct. But the Event RegionEntered is never called and e.Beacons.Length in DidRangeBeacons event is always 0.

```
locationMgr.DidRangeBeacons += (object sender, CLRegionBeaconsRangedEventArgs e) => {
            var a = e.Region;
            if (e.Beacons.Length > 0) {
           //make notification
         }
}
```

The difference from above mentioned sample is that I use the IBeacon instead of IPad.

Answer (score 0):

Check to be sure you know the ProcimityUUID of your beacon by using the [Locate](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8) app for iOS.  You will need to configure the app with your ProximityUUID.

If the app will not detect your beacon, the beacon may be misconfigured or you may not have the proper UUID.

**EDIT:**  I have added instructions for how to scan for your ProximityUUID [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33936873/1461050)

Comment: Thanks for your response @davidgyoung, I have downloaded the app. My beacon was not listed and configured manually but without any result. The beacon is not visible in Locate app.