# Could not find IBeacon

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, locate

Having the trouble to connect to IBeacon, I have downloaded the [Locate app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8) but it was unable to find my IBeacon. I have also manually configured the ibeacon but without success. Another approach was that I have downloaded the [eBeacon app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ebeacon-ibeacon-eddystone/id730279939?mt=8) and my IBeacon is visible only in central peripherals, not in the list of Beacons.

I think the problem is in the device. Here it is [my beacon](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Bluetooth-Broadcasting-Sensor-BLE-Ibeacon-Low-Energy-Device-Beacons-With-Battery-/131659545016).

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Thanks!

P.S
I have asked the question about the problems for connection to IBeacon [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914654/problems-with-connecting-to-ibeacon/33915452#33915452).

Comment: Did you set correctly its UUID in order to find it?

Comment: Actually I did, but the UUID which seller wrote me seems incorrect. I found it manually by eBeacon App, which gives an information about Bluetooth device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggest in your comment, the most likely explanation is that **the beacon is not broadcasting a ProximityUUID that is configured into your iOS devices**.  More general bluetooth scanning apps for iOS will show the service UUID for a device, but this is not the same as the ProximityUUID, even though superficially it looks the same.  This can be very misleading.

Unfortunately, **iOS has a security mechanism that does not allow you to read the identifiers of an iBeacon** unless you know the ProximityUUID up front.  Fortunately, other platforms do not have this restriction.  Two alternatives are:

- **Android** - [Locate app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en) (free)
- **Mac** - [ScanBeacon](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/scanbeacon/id768901501?mt=12) ($10)
- **Linux** - [ScanBeacon Ruby Gem](https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/scanbeacon-gem) (free)

If you have one of the above platforms with BLE support (or can borrow one), you can use this to scan for the beacon and get its ProximityUUID.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me too much. Android Locate app have found real ProximityUUID.